# circular dependency between app project and internal db library in android

Tags: java, android, circular-dependency

I am facing a situation while accessing my DB layer from the andriod code. I have my app project and for database I have created an internal Library that takes care of DB operations.

I have an interface exposed from DB layer, which is implemented by the DB manager class in DB library.

The interface has methods related to common SQL operations, such as insert, select etc.

Now, when I am calling one of these methods to pass my data from the app to DB library, I want to do this on objects. In My case I have a common base class from which all Model classes are inherited.

However, when I try to add a method in my DB interface which takes this base object as a parameter, android studio complains of circular dependency.

For the time being, I may use the Map, or some other data structures to send and receive data to and from my DB library. However, I want to solve this problem in a standard fashion.

I know that there is something i have to do related to dependency inversion principle, but i am just not getting a hint on how I can make my coupling loose for this case by using abstractions.

can some one please give some hint to proceed forward ?

Interface:

```
public interface DbItf {
    public void close();
   //For country table
    public Map<String,String> selectCtrs(Context m_context, String qry);
    long saveCtrList(Map<String, String> ctrMp, String qry, Context appContext);
}
```

Instead I want to do this:

```
public interface DbItf {
    public void close();
   //For country table
    public List<MyObject> selectCtrs(Context m_context, String qry);
    long saveCtrList(List<MyObject>, String qry, Context appContext);
}
```

My app project model classes accesses this interface in following way:

```
 @Override
    public long saveToLocal(String qry) {

       AppCtrl.getInstance().initDB();
       long retc = 0;
       retc = AppCtrl.getInstance().getQeeDbItf().saveCtrList(AppCtrl.getInstance().getCtrMp(), qry, AppCtrl.getInstance().getAppContext());
       return retc;
    }

    @Override
    public void openFrmLocal(String qry) {
        AppCtrl.getInstance().initDB();

       Map<String,String> locMp = AppCtrl.getInstance().getQeeDbItf().selectCtrs(AppCtrl.getInstance().getAppContext(), qry);

       if (locMp.size() > 0 ) {
           Log.d("openFrmLocal", "" + String.valueOf(locMp.size()));
           AppCtrl.getInstance().setCtrMp(locMp);
       }

    }
```

Thanks

Comment: What if you take out the model classes out of the main app and put them in another library? DB lib will depend on Model lib and Main app will depend on DB lib and Model lib

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope to have understood your problem / system architecture.

Anyway, just define a DataBaseObject interface, implemented by the object you will write in the database and used by the Database.

In this way, you can import the interface from both the classes/libraries, but only the DataBaseObject will have a direct pointer to the database and not viceversa.

Comment: hmm i shall try this, this is interesting. I got stuck at just one interface!